# Silver-plating copper cookware

Tags: copper-cookware, silver

Back in the day, I had a friend who was a fine chef. Her best personal pans were silver-lined copper, and occasionally, she would send them away for re-plating.

Is  electroplating to  a culinary standard, or at least refreshing the plate, something that could be done at home with a brush-plating kit, or does the layer have to be thicker than can be achieved this way?

Comment: Hey, I don't think that SA is going to be a great place to find answers for this.  Maybe try DIY or Crafts?

Comment: Are you sure they were silver-plated? Normally, copper cookware gets tinned.

Comment: Silver-plated cookware is a thing.  So is solid silver cookware, believe it or don't.   Silver is a really good conductor. https://duparquet.com/products/silver-lined-copper-cookware

Comment: @FuzzyChef Point taken ..  I thought there was a chance that on this stack there may be others who  specialize in the culinary application, but if a mod suggests this is off-topic, I'll transfer without complaint... rumtscho, yes, silver, and part of the reason for this q. was that, surprisingly, home-plating would work out cheaper than 3rd-party tinning, if a thin plate suffices.

Comment: It's not off-topic, I just don't know that we have a lot of metalworker types here.I'm probably the most knowledgable of our regular answerers, and I don't know the answr to this question.